# Sending the number of products via email in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shopify, google-sheets-macros

I have a google sheets tool where I automatically get the number of products on our site every hour with the Shopify API.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m1lF6jLWPIKhJDOut_G-2tX_zYW4fU9dHKwIs03rr1Y/edit?usp=sharing

I need to develop a code for this tool. This code will check this product number after each product number search and if this product number is below 1000, it should send me a mail informing the product number. How can I improve this?

**The function that takes the number of products from the site**

```
function _1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startCol = 1
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();

  var rawtext = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri.json").getContentText()
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(rawtext);
  var contentObj = jsonObj.collection

  var columns = Object.keys(contentObj)

  var colName = []
  var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
    var key = columns[i]
    var value = contentObj[key]
    result.push(value)
  }

  var numRow = 1
  var numCol = columns.length
  if(lastRow+1 == 1){
    spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow+1, startCol, numRow, numCol).setValues([columns]);
    spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow+2, startCol, numRow, numCol).setValues([result]);
  }else {
    spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow+1, startCol, numRow, numCol).setValues([result]);
  }


  spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow+1, startCol).activate();
};
```

**The function that should take the Products Count number of the last row and send mail if it is less than 1000.** (It is not working and has not been completed yet.) https://gyazo.com/e2fd5cdc4043dec00da1fce0e3c6c0ca (6562 is products count)

```
function SendEmail() {
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // I need your help in here. How can I get the products count in the last row after each run?

  // Check totals sales
  if (productsCount < 1000){ 
  // Send Alert Email.
  var message = 'KolayOto Lastik Ürün Sayısı Uyarısı!'; // Second column
  var subject = 'Ürün sayısı uyarısı!';
  MailApp.sendEmail("bbelcioglu@sekizgen.com", subject, message);
  MailApp.sendEmail("berk.belcioglu@gmail.com", subject, message);
  }
}
```

I hope I could explain the problems enough. I would be glad if you help.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the functions of `_1` and `goToFirstColumnAfterLastRowWithData`?

Comment: @Tanaike _1 is reads the product number from the json link in the function and adds it to the end of the sheet and goToFirstColumnAfterLastRowWithData is not working anyway, no need to consider. I even delete that code. I want your help from what I have to do there. What I want is a code that gets the number of products on the last line after the _1 function works and if it is less than 1000 it should send me an email.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the Products Count number from the URL using Google Apps Script.

  - In this case, you want to return the value of `6562`.
- You want to return that value at the function of `_1()`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- When the returned value from the URL is seen, the Products Count number can be retrieved with `contentObj.products_count`.

#### Modified script:

When your script of `_1()` is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
  spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow+1, startCol).activate();
};
```

To:

```
  spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow+1, startCol).activate();

  return contentObj.products_count;  // <--- Added
};
```

And, by above modification, `SendEmail()` can be modified as follows.

```
function SendEmail() {
  var productsCount = _1(); // <--- Added

  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // I need your help in here. How can I get the products count in the last row after each run?

  // Check totals sales
  if (productsCount < 1000){ 
  // Send Alert Email.
  var message = 'KolayOto Lastik Ürün Sayısı Uyarısı!'; // Second column
  var subject = 'Ürün sayısı uyarısı!';
  MailApp.sendEmail("bbelcioglu@sekizgen.com", subject, message);
  MailApp.sendEmail("berk.belcioglu@gmail.com", subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Berk B. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.